# How to calculate age in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

TABLE:

```
ID    pet_aggg    pet_year    pet_month    pet_date
1     birth       0           0            02/03/2017
2     birth       0           0            05/02/2017
3     birth       0           0            12/01/2017
4     age         10          6            0
5     age         6           8            0
```

I want to calculate all pet where pet age less than 4 months.

Query:

```
SELECT count("*") as Total 
FROM `pet_info` 
CASE WHEN `pet_info` == 'birth' 
    THEN `pet_date` HAVING BETWEEN >= '02/01/2017' AND <= '02/05/2017' 
CASE WHEN `pet_info` == 'birth' 
    THEN `pet_month` HAVING <= 4;
```

In my new query, I want to select all data where pet less than 4 months old.

```
SELECT * FROM `pet_info` 
CASE WHEN `pet_info` == 'birth' 
    THEN WHERE `pet_date` BETWEEN >= '02/01/2017' AND <= '02/05/2017' 
CASE WHEN `pet_info` == 'birth' 
    THEN WHERE `pet_month` <= 4;
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: SELECT * FROM `pet_info` where ( CASE WHEN `pet_info` == 'birth' THEN  `pet_date` BETWEEN '02/01/2017' AND  '02/05/2017' WHEN `pet_info` == 'birth' THEN  `pet_month` <= 4);

Comment: @JYoThI SELECT * FROM `pet_info` where ( CASE WHEN `pet_info`.`pet_aggg` == 'birth' THEN `pet_info`.`pet_date` BETWEEN '02/01/2017' AND '02/05/2017' WHEN `pet_info`.`pet_aggg` == 'age' THEN `pet_info`.`pet_month` <= 4);  SQL SYNTAX ERROR

Comment: show me the  exact error

Comment: @JYoThI  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== 'birth' THEN `pet_info`.`pet_date` BETWEEN '02/01/2017' AND '02/05/2017' WHEN' at line 1

Comment: user single = not ==

Comment: try this SELECT * FROM pet_info where ( CASE WHEN pet_info = 'birth' THEN pet_date BETWEEN '02/01/2017' AND '02/05/2017' WHEN pet_info = 'birth' THEN pet_month <= 4);

Comment: Whenever possible put dates in a `DATE` field in [ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (`YYYY-MM-DD`) so they can be sorted, indexed, and compared in a meaningful way. You can do any conversion for display by the user later, and at that point take into account things like the user's personal preferences.

Comment: You need to learn basic SQL syntax. `SELECT cols FROM table WHERE conditions`

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` condition `CASE` should be like this

```
SELECT * FROM pet_info 
where ( CASE WHEN pet_info = 'birth'
             THEN pet_date BETWEEN '02/01/2017' AND '02/05/2017' 
             WHEN pet_info = 'age' THEN pet_month <= 4  END);
```

Comment: It makes no sense to have the same `WHEN` clause twice in a `CASE`. You're also missing the `END` for `CASE`.

Comment: THANKSSS @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of problems with basic syntax. The syntax of a SQL query (simplified) is:

```
SELECT some cols
FROM tableName
WHERE conditions
```

You don't put `WHERE` inside the `CASE` expressions. And if you use `BETWEEN`, you don't also write `>=` and `<=` -- `x BETWEEN y AND z` is short for `x >= y AND x <= z`.

Another problem you have is that your dates are not formatted properly for comparisons. If you do `pet_date BETWEEN '02/01/2017' AND <= '02/05/2017'`, the date `02/03/2016` will match it, because it's doing lexicographic comparisons, not date comparisons. You should change that column to a `DATE` datatype rather than `CHAR`. If you can't do this, you should use `STR_TO_DATE()` to convert it to a date when comparing.

The query should then be:

```
SELECT *
FROM pet_info
WHERE (pet_aggg = 'birth' AND STR_TO_DATE(pet_date, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '2017-01-02' AND '2017-05-02')
   OR (pet_aggg = 'age' AND pet_month <= 4)
```

And instead of putting specific dates into the query, you could just use `STR_TO_DATE(pet_date, '%d/%m/%Y') >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH)`